# calculate payment percentage of one category for each city

Tags: sql, join, percentage

I have this database
[image]

and we need to calculate the payment percentage for every category in each city
I'm trying to do this

```
    select SUM(ShipQty), SUM(ShipQty)*100/(select SUM(ShipQty) from InvoiceLineitemes 
inner join Invoice on InvoiceLineitemes.InvoiceNumber=Invoice.InvoiceNumber 
inner join Customers on Invoice.SoldToCustomer=Customers.CustomerNumber group by City),
Category,city from InvoiceLineitemes
inner join Inventory on InvoiceLineitemes.ItemNumber=Inventory.ItemNumber 
inner join Invoice on InvoiceLineitemes.InvoiceNumber=Invoice.InvoiceNumber 
inner join Customers on Invoice.SoldToCustomer=Customers.CustomerNumber 
group by Category ,City
```

but im facing this error

msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results and an explanation of the the query should be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want a ratio of a part to a whole.  This best approached using window functions:

```
select Category, city,
       sum(ShipQty),
       sum(ShipQty) * 100.0 / sum(sum(shipqty)) over (partition by city)
from InvoiceLineitemes ili join
     Inventory i
     on ili.ItemNumber = i.ItemNumber join
     Invoice inv
     on ili.InvoiceNumber = inv.InvoiceNumber join
     Customers c
     on inv.SoldToCustomer = c.CustomerNumber 
group by Category, City;
```

Note that table aliases also make the query easier to write and to read.